# Typescript testable functional programming

Tags: typescript, oop, functional-programming

I have an OOP background and I'm coming from C#/Java.

Lately, I encountered a phenomenon where I could not easily test my typescript code in some places.

For example, I got a couple of files that contain more or less the following code:

```
const fooStorage: LocalForage = createInstance({...});

export const addFoo = (foo: Foo): Promise<void> => {
    await fooStorage.setItem(foo.id, foo);
}

// Other crud functions for example
```

Now, testing this seems kinda awkward/unusual. From an OOP standpoint, I would have some class `FooCrud` which would receive a `LocalForage` object in the constructor, applying DI. Thus I could mock the `LocalForage` instance.

In the case presented above, I thought about having the methods receive a `LocalForage` instance which would have by default the `fooStorage` object. Basically this: `const addFoo = (foo: Foo, storage: LocalForage = fooStorage) => {}`.

Is this a viable strategy? I know in the first case my function is impure but I can't seem to find a way to refactor it besides what I mentioned above.

What approach should I use, can anyone provide an example/resources where I can see such cases that can be tested?

And besides the example provided here, I have other files where I'm building some functions on top of an `Axios` instance or a `zustand` store. I found it difficult to test those functionalities as well.

Comment: Since the function is impure anyway, you could use dependency injection or partial application to pass the storage thing around. That'll neither make the code more nor less functional, because it isn't really functional to begin with. See my article series [From dependency injection to dependency rejection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection) for more details.

Comment: "Is this a viable strategy?" Yes. Having an optional parameter for mocking that defaults to the closed over real thing is a perfectly viable strategy.